# Insert into table white result

Tags: php, database, postgresql

i'm trying to do an insert into a Postgres table. But i don't understand why it fails. ( I tried in mysql and it works ).
This is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE public.prenotazione
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('prenotazione_id_seq'::regclass),
    "nominativo " character(45) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "email " character(45) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "oggetto " character(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    orario_inizio time(6) without time zone,
    orario_fine time(6) without time zone,
    "nominativoi " character(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    emaili character(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "nominativoe " character(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    emaile character(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    stanza integer,
    data date
)
```

**config.php**

```
<?php 
$dbname = "postgres";
$host = "localhost";
$username = "postgres";

$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host", $username, 123456789 ); 
?>
```

This is my input file.

```
<?php
//Connecting to db here

require ('config.php');

// Richiedente
$nominativo = $_POST['nominativo'];

$email = $_POST['email'];
$oggetto = $_POST['oggetto'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$orario_inizio = $_POST['orario_inizio'];
$orario_fine = $_POST['orario_fine'];
$stanza = 0;

// Personale Interno
$nominativoi = $_POST['nominativoi'];
$emaili = $_POST['emaili'];

// Persona Esterno
$nominativoe = $_POST['nominativoe'];
$emaile = $_POST['emaile'];

//aggiunta di un'ora ( per tornare indietro cambiare $newTimeEnd con $orario_fine
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $orario_fine);
$dateInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 hour');

$dateTime->add($dateInterval);

$newTimeEnd = $dateTime->format('H:i');


//checkdata = query per il controllo delle prenotazioni.
$checkdata = "SELECT count(*) as prenotato
  FROM Prenotazione
 WHERE data='$data'
   AND NOT ('$newTimeEnd' < orario_inizio OR orario_fine < '$orario_inizio')";

$querycheck = $dbh->prepare($checkdata);
$querycheck->execute();
$prenotato = $querycheck->fetch()[0];
var_dump($prenotato);
if ($prenotato == 0 AND $stanza == 0 ) { 
$query1 = "INSERT INTO prenotazione (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile,stanza) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$newTimeEnd','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile',1)";
    var_dump($query1);
    $result1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);
    $result1->execute();
    $rex = 1;        
    $rex = 1;
}
else if ($prenotato == 1){
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO Prenotazione (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile,stanza) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$orario_fine','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile',2)";
    $result1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);
    $result1->execute();
    $rex = 1;
}
else
{
      $rex = 0;
}

?>
```

And i receive this with var_dump

> NULL string(259) "INSERT INTO prenotazione
>   (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile,stanza)
>   VALUES ('aaa
>   aaaa','aaa@email.com','2018-10-04','09:30','12:30','aaaaa','bbbb
>   bbbb','bbbb@email.com','cccc ccc','cccc@email.com',1)"

In your opinion how can i do to solve this problem?
Thank

Comment: Try to get the error paste this after the prepare
`if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    die();
}` .  Assuming you are using PDO

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is the result: 
string(1) "0" string(246) "INSERT INTO prenotazione (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile,stanza) VALUES ('aaa aaaa','aaa@email.com','2018-10-04','09:30','12:30','aaaa','bbb','bbb@email.com','cccc','ccc@email.com',1)"

Comment: Try that query in PHPMyAdmin, see if it returns any error

Comment: @Mike Why in my PhPMyAdmin? I'm using postgres

Comment: What I meant, try it to run it in your mysql database rather then your code. To check if the query is correct.

Comment: @Mike Yes the query in Mysql goes well! I have tried. When i'm migrate to postgres I only change something like the structure of: $querycheck = $dbh->prepare($checkdata); $querycheck->execute(); 
because in mysql it was slightly different and here it gave me error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is very relaxed with syntax, this might be a plus when you are not a database expert but can lead to "surprising" errors when it makes wrong assumptions.
On the other hand PostgreSQL tends to be very strict when it comes to data definition. You have told Postgres your fields are named:

> "nominativo " with quotes and blank space, not nominativo
>
> "email " with quotes and blank space, not email
>
> "oggetto " with quotes and blank space, not oggetto
>
> "nominativoi " with quotes and blank space, not nominativoi
>
> "nominativoe " with quotes and blank space, not nominativoe

So it is saying you nominativo, email, oggetto, nominativoi and nominativoe columns do not exist.

This sentence:

```
    INSERT INTO prenotazione (
    "nominativo ","email ",data,orario_inizio,
    orario_fine,"oggetto ","nominativoi ",emaili,
    "nominativoe ",emaile,stanza)
    VALUES ('aaa aaaa','aaa@email.com','2018-10-04',
    '09:30','12:30','aaaaa','bbbb bbbb','bbbb@email.com','cccc 
    ccc','cccc@email.com',1);
```

Works perfectly.

For postgres "nominativo " and nominativo are not the same, "surprisingly" they are for MySQL

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I change in $query1 = "INSERT INTO prenotazione ("nominativo","email",data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,"oggetto","nominativoi","emaili","nominativoe","emaile",stanza) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$newTimeEnd','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile',1)"; But i receive this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'nominativo' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\input.php on line 44

Comment: Also... (this is not an error in here but just be careful) beware with schemas, if you define table as public.prenotazione it can only be called prenotazione when public schema is your current schema, you may find it's not true (i.e.) on database hosting, so just define table as prenotazione and don't assume public is your default schema or use it as public.prenotazione.

Comment: You need to escape double quotes \"nominativo \" not "nominativo" since your PHP string is double quoted. And don't forget your blank space :)

Comment: so i should do INSERT INTO prenotazione (" \"nominativo \", \"email \"...) ?

Comment: $query1 = "INSERT INTO prenotazione (\"nominativo \",\"email \",data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,\"oggetto \",\"nominativoi \",emaili,\"nominativoe \",emaile,stanza) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$newTimeEnd','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile',1)"
 If I have not mistaken with substitutions

Comment: definitely i hate postgres but I love you haha ​​thank you so much you saved me.

Comment: You are welcome. The original sin in here was naming tables with a blank space, postgres just let you know your were doing so in case you are not aware, imagine the "stupid" scenario when you have columns "nominativo " and nominativo not necessarily on same table but on same SELECT, you might start loving the "punctilious" postgres instead of the "apathetic" mysql ^_^

Comment: Maybe it is too much "punctilious" xD

Comment: I'm doing some tests and I tried to create a table without using the quotes "", so for example the name etc.
Obviously removing what you told me to add previously in the insert and it does not go! Really strange

Comment: Add a try -> catch block and dump error messages, you can not debug errors without knowing what is happening, you can read about it here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Alternatively you can chek postgres logs but they may have a bit of delay on most logger facilities.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for PHP comparing `null == 0` will result to [true](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Your script is then resolving the if condition `$prenotato == 0 AND $stanza == 0` as TRUE and TRUE and proceed to print the second var dump.